# How to append Text at the begining of a file?

Tags: vb.net, string, file, text

I'm using the command `IO.File.AppendAllLines("3.txt", "text", System.Text.Encoding.Default)`
to write to `3.txt`.
But the string is writing in down.
How I can write a string upper?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of the relevant source code, a sample of the output that it's producing, and a sample of the output that you'd like for it to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Call the strings ToUpper method to make the string upper case

IO.File.AppendAllLines("3.txt", "text".ToUpper(), System.Text.Encoding.Default)

Answer (score 0):

The `.Append()` method will always append(add) the given string to an existing content. so n this case you cannot do like this.

I suggest you to read the content first, write the content back to the file along with the additional string. If you are expecting this, then the following code will help you:

```
var currentContent= File.ReadAllText(@"D:\3.txt");
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\3.txt", "Some string" + currentContent);
// here you are adding "Some string" at the begining of the file
```